# Как работать с Google Maps в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, google-maps

Нужно разработать JavaFX приложение, в котором будет интеграция с сервисом Google Maps. Желательно не просто html страничка, которую можно отобразить на форме. Как это сделать?

Comment: Идем в гугл и получаем https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/gmapsfx-add-google-maps-to-your-javafx-application/

Comment: Там используется JavaScript

Comment: Значит гуглим дальше )

Comment: Я гуглил, да толкового ничего не нашел

Comment: А это? http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/

Comment: Без js похоже никак https://habr.com/post/170141/

Comment: Плохо искали . GMapsFX = https://www.google.com/amp/s/rterp.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/gmapsfx-add-google-maps-to-your-javafx-application/amp/